# Transform Object attribute to array of object

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I want to merge Array of ObjectA containing ObjectB attribute by ObjectA attribute.

For example :

```
let myArray = [
  { name: 'Jeu', series: { name: 'testA', value: '89' } },
  { name: 'Dim', series: { name: 'testB', value: '490' } },
  { name: 'Dim', series: { name: 'testC', value: '978' } }
]
```

And I would like to transform it to

```
[
  { name: 'Jeu', series: { name: 'testA', value: '89' } },
  { name: 'Dim', series: [{ name: 'testB', value: '490' },{ name: 'testC', value: '978' } ] }
]
```

Am I able to do that with a simple reduce/map loop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) (with some [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)) to build an object that maps unique names and objects in the format you want to have, grouping series by name. Then, you can simply get the values from this object.

```js
const myArray = [
  { name: 'Jeu', series: { name: 'testA', value: '89' } },
  { name: 'Dim', series: { name: 'testB', value: '490' } },
  { name: 'Dim', series: { name: 'testC', value: '978' } }
];

const map = myArray.reduce(
  (acc, curr) => ({
    ...acc,
    [curr.name]: {
      name: curr.name,
      series: acc[curr.name]
        ? [...acc[curr.name].series, curr.series]
        : [curr.series]
    }
  }),
  {}
);

const output = Object.values(map);
console.log(output);
```